# SQL Create a table with max values

Tags: sql

Hi I have a table where I have various values associated with an ID, and want to create a table in which there's only a single row per ID, and that row has the max value. For example if the input is:

```
ID   VALUE
-----------
A     10
A     20
B     30
B     40
```

then the output is:

```
ID   VALUE
----------- 
A     20
B     40
```

Comment: You realize that this would require continual updating.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`CTAs`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/CTAS):

```
-- this will require refreshing and won't work on every RDBMS
CREATE TABLE table_name2 AS
SELECT ID, MAX(VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM table_name
GROUP BY ID;
```

or create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT ID, MAX(VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM table_name
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: CTAs mentioned but not included?

Comment: @JonScott `CREATE TABLE AS statement`

Comment: Maybe @JonScott confused Oracle CTAs with Sql Server CTEs, like I did.

Comment: @DanBracuk Probably you are right. TIL: [CTAs in Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-as-select-azure-sql-data-warehouse)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS qtab1
   AS
   SELECT id, max(value)
      FROM tab1
    group by id;
```